# Creating custom shell using scala

Tags: scala, shell

I need recommendation on shell/cli framework. Use case is very simple - I have bunch of commands which would accept arbitrary number of arguments and will result in output on screen.

Please note that I'm strictly after shell and *not* cli parsing (like [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt)).

Any advises and/or recommendations are welcome. As of now I can't really find any.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in the [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/). It provides a variety of tools for writing scripts with scala. You can look at this small [example script](https://github.com/rodionovp/graphql-schema-compatibility-checker/blob/master/check-schema). Ammonite also allows you to define all of the script dependencies in the same file by using imports like this one (this syntax is even [supported by Intellij IDEA](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2018/05/07/ammonite-support/)):

```
import $ivy.`org.scalaj::scalaj-http:2.3.0`, scalaj.http.Http
```

If the script startup time is a concern for you, then I can recommend you to check out [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) and [native-image](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/aot-compilation/) tool in particular. It allows you to compile any JVM application as a native binary. It also does an AOT (Ahead-of-time) compilation which dramatically reduces the startup time of a JVM application (down to ~1-10ms).